# html: price listing based on email

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website for a customer who may not be very computer literate. This person knows how to use email. How can I build a website (purely html, javascript) where he can email his latest prices and the website automatically updates itself. I dont think he would be literate enough to FTP file some where. Is it possible?

How to build a secure login page and redirect to order page using only javascript and html?

How to create secure administrative section on javascript/html only website?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the limit to use only JavaScript and HTML?  Your username and previous questions imply familiarity with server-side code.  If it's all JS and HTML then security is going to be difficult since _everything_ is client-side.

Comment: A friend of mine needs to build this who is only HTML and Javascript literal and I can not help him with server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to create a nice admin web interface, and teach him how to use it. Or, agree some kind of Excel format for product prices, and teach the steps of uploading a csv file. Doing things by email would complicate things in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

As in the website receives the email as data input?  That's probably not going to work very well.  Also, if the client is as you imply, expect those emails to be poorly formatted, filled with typos, etc.  It's not a very good data entry medium by any means.

The ideal solution would be to build an admin page into the website where the client can enter the information in as controlled a manner as possible, validating the information on the spot rather than through an email (would the server send a reply email for invalid data?  that would get infuriating quickly).  A simple and intuitive UI should be able to overcome any computer literacy issues he may have.

Comment: One small caveat here: server scripting required (although it pretty much is for any solution)

Comment: @cobbal: It'll be required for the mail idea as well, only more of it and more complicated.  Unless he builds some kind of mail client in JavaScript and basically publicly opens access to a mail box (as ChristopheD mentions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done purely in HTML/Javascript. It would need a server component. You would have to set up some sort of POP3 or IMAP listener that polls a mail server for correctly formatted email then dumps that into a database to update the site. Certainly not trivial.

I would build an administration portion of the site to allow the customer to log in and enter the data...no matter how illiterate, they certainly can be trained. ;-)

Comment: Alternatively, configure a mail server that processes the incoming mail directly.  Possibly a little more up-front work, but over time it'd be way less of a hassle than dealing with POP or (gag) IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `mail your prices` thing work by just regulary checking a specific mailbox (over POP3 for example).

But that's something you won't be able to do in only pure html / javascript (and consider this: you would also need to store the mailbox credentials in client side code then!)

Answer (score 0):

Email is a store-and-forward, asynchronous transport. You can use it to transport:

- plain text (the body of an email)
- styled text (the html body of a MIME email)
- attached files

But none of those options will work well in your use case. You'd have to try to parse the body of the email if you were looking in the body for update information. -- Bad idea

And if you're using email to transport ordered data such as csv or Excel files, uploading the files directly to the website would enable a much better user interface.

You shouldn't use Excel files either since it will be too complicated for your user--he'd need to get the column (field) names exactly right, the content cells would also need to be exactly right, etc. Eg I use an excel file for input on one of my systems and a constant problem is zip/postal codes since they look like numbers but can have significant leading zeroes. Few users know how to enter them...

**Recommendation** create a set of web forms in the administrative section of the website. Your customer will be happy and you'll be even happier due to lower volume of support calls.